# invalid input syntax for type uuid

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs

well, I'm making an api with rabbitmq, where one part I want the user with enough prestige to be able to update the question of a random user, who can vote or give a negative vote, thus changing that user's prestige, losing prestige due to a negative vote or improving due to a positive vote, but to me it seems right but it returns an error saying that:

Error:

```
invalid input syntax for type uuid: "{"idUsuario":"d7b24127-32d5-4936-a53f-4b5c690de8a1","idUsuarioPropio":"4b4bae21-ecfb-4f10-af23-4a2dc50e34a5","id":"d6259a4f-eb25-494f-bc65-1161107d6b8f","voto":-1,"titulo":"opa eai","pergunta":"e assim e assim opa eai cara como e"}"
```

my codes:

my usuarioPrestigiadoAtualiza(User with sufficient prestige updates and votes or down votes on a user's question):

```
async usuarioPrestigiadoAtualiza(idUsuario: string, idUsuarioPropio: string,  dados: atualizaEspecificoDTO){
    const { id, titulo, pergunta, voto } = dados
    const usuario = await this.usuarioMetaRepository.findOne({where: {id: idUsuario}})
    if(usuario === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('Usuario Prestigiado nao existe')
    }
    const usuario2 = await this.usuarioMetaRepository.findOne({where: {id: idUsuarioPropio}})
    if(usuario2 === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('Usuario Propio nao existe')
    }
    if(usuario2.pergunta.id !== id){
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Usuario Propio nao possui essa pergunta')
    }
    const perguntaAchada = await this.perguntaRepository.findOne({where: {id}})
    if(perguntaAchada === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('Pergunta nao existe')
    }
    const perguntaEntidade = new PerguntaEntidade()

    perguntaEntidade.id = id
    perguntaEntidade.titulo = titulo
    perguntaEntidade.pergunta = pergunta
    perguntaEntidade.voto = voto
    

    if(usuario.prestigio < 100){
      throw new UnauthorizedException(`Usuario: ${usuario.nome} nao possui prestigio suficiente!`)
    }
    if(voto === -1){
      usuario2.prestigio - 5
      usuario2.voteForce - 2
    }
    if(voto > 1){
      for(let i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
        if(usuario2.pergunta.voto + 1){
          usuario2.prestigio + 4
          usuario2.voteForce + 1
        }
      }
    }
    if(usuario.voteForce > 30){
      voto * 2
    }
    if(usuario.voteForce > 60){
      voto * 3
    }
    if(usuario.voteForce >= 100){
      voto * 4
    }
    if(usuario2.prestigio > 100){
      usuario2.prestigio === 100
    }
    if(voto === -10){
      return await this.perguntaRepository.remove(perguntaAchada)
    }

    const perguntaMudadaPorPrestigiado = await this.perguntaRepository.save(perguntaEntidade)
    return perguntaMudadaPorPrestigiado

  }
```

my controler:

```
@MessagePattern({ cmd: 'put-perguntaPrestigio'})
  async enviarPerguntaAvaliada(@Ctx() contexto: RmqContext, @Payload() id: string, @Payload() id2: string,  @Payload() dados: atualizaEspecificoDTO){
    const channel = contexto.getChannelRef()
    const message = contexto.getMessage()
    channel.ack(message)

    return this.perguntaService.usuarioPrestigiadoAtualiza(id, id2, dados)
```

my api gateway controler:

```
@Put('usuarioM/:id1/:id2/:id3')
  async perguntaAtualizaPorPrestigiado(@Param('id1') idUsuario: string, @Param('id2') idUsuarioPropio: string, @Param('id3') id: string,  @Body() data: atualizaEspecificoDTO) {
    return this.authServico.send(
      {
        cmd: 'put-perguntaPrestigio'
      }, {idUsuario, idUsuarioPropio, id, ...data}
    )
  }
```

my dto postman

```
{
    "voto":  -1,
    "titulo": "opa eai",
    "pergunta": "e assim e assim opa eai cara como e"
}
```

my create question:

```
export class criarPerguntaDTO  {
  @IsUUID()
  id: string
  @IsNumber()
  voto: number
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MaxLength(100, {message: 'limite de 100 caracteres de titulo'})
  titulo: string

  @IsNotEmpty()
  pergunta: string

}
```

As I said, when I give a send, this error comes back to me, I wanted this user with sufficient privilege to update the question and if a -1 is inserted, the user who asked would lose privilege, or vice versa if the vote(voto) is good, but give me this error, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Payload()` returns the entire payload object, not just a part of it, so you only need it once `@Payload() payload: { idUsuario: string; idUsuarioPropio: string;  dados: atualizaEspecificoDTO }` and then you can access `payload.idUsuario`, `payload.idUsuarioPropio`, etc

Comment: it worked, but now gives: ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'dados' as it is undefined., is from my request? or some of these 3 ids not exist?